# error opening pcap in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pcap

i use anaconda with pyhon 2.7, i want to open pcap file and extract some features 
here the code

```
from steelscript.wireshark.core.pcap import PcapFile
pcap = PcapFile('sample.pcap')
pcap.info()
```

the error :

---

```
WindowsError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2022afd405ae> in <module>()
  2 
  3 pcap = PcapFile('sample.pcap')
----> 4 pcap.info()

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\steelscript\wireshark\core\pcap.pyc in   info(self)
   44             cmd = ['capinfos', '-A', '-m', '-T', self.filename]
   45             logger.info('subprocess: %s' % ' '.join(cmd))
---> 46             capinfos = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
   47             hdrs, vals = (capinfos.split('\n')[:2])
   48             self._info = dict(zip(hdrs.split(','), vals.split(',')))

C:\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.pyc in check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs)
   564     if 'stdout' in kwargs:
   565         raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
--> 566     process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    567     output, unused_err = process.communicate()
     568     retcode = process.poll()

   C:\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.pyc in __init__(self, args, bufsize,      executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags)
    708                                 p2cread, p2cwrite,
    709                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
 --> 710                                 errread, errwrite)
    711         except Exception:
    712             # Preserve original exception in case os.close raises.

 C:\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.pyc in _execute_child(self, args, executable,      preexec_fn, close_fds, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags,   shell, to_close, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite)
    956                                          env,
    957                                          cwd,
-- > 958                                          startupinfo)
    959             except pywintypes.error, e:
    960                 # Translate pywintypes.error to WindowsError, which     is
```

### WindowsError: [Error 2]

i search the web and find to edit subprocess.py but i can not open it and edit the code. when i try to open it and show me message "would you like to search the web for program to open it", windows does not recognize it.
2- i install dpkt module in the scripts folder successfully  but pandas when i import the module show error : there is no such module 
thanks alot

Comment: Why did you tag this question with `pandas`?

Comment: i am sorry for that, my intent is to right ipython notebook, i need help i do not know what to do

Comment: is it possible no one know the answer?

Comment: Not many people are interested in investing a lot of time to understand a problem (we don't know your .pcap file) so reproducing is very difficult for us. Your goal should be to make it as easy as possible to reproduce and thus understand the underlying issue. For that a [mcve] is always a good starting point.

Comment: thank you for reply, i will keep this in my mind next time. i go line by line and the problem is with pcap.info(),
 the file is dataset from the web "http://digitalcorpora.org/corp/nps/packets/2008-nitroba/nitroba.pcap"